# jsonschema mongodb not validate from .js file

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have `mongo.js` commands to create collection, here is in my `.js` file:

```
let organizationSchema = {
    bsonType: "object",
    properties: {
        name: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "must be a string and required"
        },
        active: {
            bsonType: "bool",
        },
        location: {
            bsonType: "string",
        },
        contactInfo: {
            // this one doest working for validate
            pattern: "/^\+?\d+(?:-\d+)*(?:\(\d+\)-\d+)*$/"
        },
        createdBy: {
            bsonType: "string",
        },
        createdAt: {
            bsonType: "date",
        },
        updatedAt: {
            bsonType: "date",
        },
        deletedAt: {
            bsonType: "date",
        },
    }
}
db.runCommand( { collMod: "organizations", validator:{ $jsonSchema: organizationSchema }, validationLevel: "strict"} )
db.organizations.createIndex( { "name": 1, "createdBy": 1, "location": 1, "active": 1} )
```

then I run `mongo "mongodb+srv://url" --username dev -p 'dev' < mongo.js`

on the `contactInfo` I do pattern for validation phone number, but when I insert data on my MongoDB Client, with invalid phone number, it was inserted, is that something wrong on that syntax on my `js` should I use strings on each keys there ??

```js
const r = /^\+?\d+(?:-\d+)*(?:\(\d+\)-\d+)*$/;


console.log(r.test("+1110988888"))
console.log(r.test("zzzzuuuu"))
```

Comment: May be you should also specify the `bsonType: "string"`.

Comment: I did that as well, but doesn't work @prasad_

Comment: Regular expression for `contactInfo` is invalid, just checked getting this error `Regular expression is invalid: nothing to repeat`, try this pattern it will work `^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: you are correct, my regex above is valid in javascript, I just copied it from javascript , is that any option to make that regex work ? @turivishal

Comment: i don't have more knowledge about regular expression, can you share your exact requirement of your pattern, for example `123-1234-1234`

Comment: regex must be a international's phone number, be able to use `(` `)`  `-` `+`